# Java socket, set connect timeout and so timeout, but still stuck when getting inputStream

Tags: java, sockets, timeout, bufferedreader

**Here's my code**

```
Socket s = new Socket();
s.setSoTimeout(5000);
s.connect(url, 5000);
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

So connect timeout and read timeout are set

but i met a link **:**
http://scfire-mtc-aa01.stream.aol.com:80/stream/1023

My code stucked at this line **:**

```
bufferedReader.readLine()；
```

now I check content-type of input stream before calling

```
bufferedReader.readLine()；
```

to avoid this problem, 
but I am still wondering why

```
bufferedReader.readLine()；
```

stuck?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You're talking to HTTP sites but you aren't sending any HTTP requests. So you don't get any HTTP responses. You are waiting for the response but the server is still waiting for the request.

Don't use Sockets for this, use URLs and URLConnections.